# jq, call another command inline

Tags: bash, jq

I would like to call another command inside of jq query.

For example,

```json
{
   hostA: "somedomain.com",
   hostB: "anotherdomain.com"
}
```

I need to transform to:

```json
{
   hostA: "123.123.123.123",
   hostB: "132.132.132.132"
}
```

Applying this command on every value:
`dig +short $value`

So, each host is transformed to IP.

Or, bash, iterate over result, reconstruct json only?

If so, what is the easiest/cleanest solution? I see it as I have to recreate second, mapping json and apply solutions from [jq, lookup 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320492/jq-replace-values-based-on-external-map) or [jq, lookup 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991305/jq-replace-keys-with-corresponding-value-in-another-file). Still, looks like a brute force solution.

Comment: There is no single pass efficient solution with `jq`, as it does not support exec-ing external commands explicitly

Comment: What if the host resolves to multiple IPs? Should it be an array in that case?

Comment: Let's assume, it is always one IP in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash arrays and iterate over it in a loop:

Took the answer from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638584/16822178

```bash
# read each item in the JSON array to an item in the Bash array
readarray -t host_array < <(jq -c '.[]' input.json)

# iterate through the Bash array
for host in "${host_array[@]}"; do
  dig +short "$host"
done
```

Comment: Thank you,

question was about possibility to call something inline. Which I was not sure if it is possible. Looks like it is not, as [inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian) mentioned. <br/>


What you are proposing is this "brute-force solution" I've mentioned. So, to reassemble JSON back with bash manually